# block sees self as the object it is sent to

Tags: ruby

I have the following code for connecting to websockets

```
class Connection < AbstractConnection
  def initialize

    @conn = WebSocket::Client::Simple.connect @url

    @conn.on :message do |event|
      puts 'received message' 
      #this is the weird part
      puts self
      event_data = event.data.to_json
      on_message event_data
    end
  end
end
```

the weird thing is that inside those blocks self is equal to Websocket:Client:Simple - and those methods I am calling inside the blocks are missing, so there is an error.

the library I am using for connecting to the websocket is this https://github.com/shokai/websocket-client-simple
and it uses event emitter gem to emit events when messages are received.

I really would expect the blocks to identify self as where they are created - as they do in .each method.

so the qustion is what is going on, and how can I call local methods.

Comment: Which line do you get the error on, and what is the error?

Comment: On_message throws a NoMethodError, no_message exists in main, but the code doesn't recognize it, as self is Websocket::Client::Simple

Comment: Where exactly do you define `on_message`?

Comment: added more context - still the weird thing is that the puts self writes #<WebSocket::Client::Simple::Client:0x00000101153478> and calling on message throws the following

undefined method `on_message' for #<WebSocket::Client::Simple::Client:0x00000101153478>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I really would expect the blocks to identify self as where they are created - as they do in .each method.

Normally this would be what happens, if the method used `yield` or `blk.call`, but in this case the `on` method [captures the block as a proc](https://github.com/shokai/event_emitter/blob/v0.2.5/lib/event_emitter/emitter.rb#L25), and later [calls it with `instance_exec`](https://github.com/shokai/event_emitter/blob/v0.2.5/lib/event_emitter/emitter.rb#L53), so it executes in the context of `WebSocket::Client::Simple::Client`.

Unfortunately there is no way to tell from the signature alone what any given method will do with a block passed to it.

One option might be to store the value of `self` in a local variable before the block. Local variables are still available from the block when it is executed in a different context.

```
# capture self
this = self
@conn.on :message do |event|
  # ...

  # use this to call methods
  this.on_message event_data
end
```